# WPF/XAML Go To Definition (F12) is not working with ObjectDataProvider

Tags: wpf, xaml, resharper, visual-studio-2019

ObjectDataProvider is used to get DataContext for main window:

```
<Window...>
    <Window.Resources>
       ...

       <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:MainWindowVM}"
                           MethodName="Instance"
                           x:Key="MainContext" />
       <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type universalSettings:SettingsVM}"
                           MethodName="Instance"
                           x:Key="SettingsContext" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource MainContext}" />
    </Window.DataContext>
    ...
```

MainWindowVM is a singleton. Everything was fine, I could easly navigate to my commands and properties with F12 before VS2019 recent updates.

```
<Button Command='{Binding ScaleCommand}' />
```

Right now if you press F12 on the "ScaleCommand" VS will always point to `public class ObjectDataProvider` instead of command or property.

With ReSharper extension F12 is working fine with example above, but the following still brings me to `public class ObjectDataProvider`:

```
<StackPandel DataContext="{StaticResource SettingsContext}">
    ...
    <Button Command='{Binding RevertSettingsCommand}' />
</StackPanel>
```

SettingsContext is in a different assembly. In that case nothing can help me anymore. I tried to reset all settings and then reinstall everything. No changes. It is just code navigation problem, program is running fine.

**Before some VS updates all worked fine, even without ReSharper.**

Looking for some help, WPF/XAML is already hard as is, losing such important feature as F12 navigation is real pain.

Comment: Why is this a SO question? If it's a bug in VS19, why don't you report this directly to the dotnet community or Microsoft?

Comment: may be I missing something and it is not a bug. I will ask question there aswell. I think alot of people using F12 key in xaml